# Redux Saga hot reloading

Tags: webpack, redux, react-redux, webpack-hmr, redux-saga

I was working on a React & Redux project. The project used to use webpack-dev-middleware and hot middleware to hot reload.

After I added Redux Saga to the project, and added saga middleware to the redux store. It seems that whenever I change the saga codes, the hot reloading will broke and display an error message:

> Provider> does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.

I understand that Saga uses generators and it is time dependent. Is it possible to hot reload the page with Sagas? just like how Redux reducers replace itself during hot reloading.

Thanks!

Comment: See discussion https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/22#issuecomment-218522365

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm working on a project with redux and redux-saga (but not react). I implemented the hot reloading of sagas using the sagaMiddleware.run() but you have to handle the module reloading and replace reducers and sagas as indicated in the link you provided (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0).

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import getSagas from '../sagas';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
  let sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(function* () {
     yield getSagas()
  })
  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/index');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
    module.hot.accept('../sagas', () => {
      const getNewSagas = require('../sagas');
      sagaTask.cancel()
      sagaTask.done.then(() => {
        sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(function* replacedSaga (action) {
          yield getNewSagas()
        })
      })
    })
  }

  return store;
}
```

An important thing to notice is the `getSagas()` function. It returns an array of freshly created generator object of sagas, you cannot have some precreated object in the array from some already running sagas. If you buid this array
only in one module, you can use directly a constant array, but if you build it
composing sagas from different modules you have to be sure to recreate sagas
from all modules, so the better way is that all modules export creating function instead of exporting a fixed saga or array of sagas.
For example it could be a function like this:

```
export default () => [
  takeEvery(SOME_ACTION, someActionSaga),
  takeEvery(OTHER_ACTION, otherActionSaga),
]
```

Obviously all sagas are restarted from beginning and if you have a complex sagas
with internal state you lose the current state.

A very similar approach is to use a dynamic saga in place of calling `sagaMidleware.run()`, it a very similar solution but you can reload subsets of the sagas and handle them in different ways. For more info see https://gist.github.com/mpolci/f44635dc761955730f8479b271151cf2

Comment: Solved my issue. @kevin, you can mark this as the right answer if it has solved your issue.

Comment: @mpolci can you explain more about the getSagas function? I understand that you want to get an array of saga generator objects, but if you have multiple saga files that export listeners, would you recommend importing each one and calling them as a chain? `import getSaga1 from '../saga1` `import getSaga2 from '../saga2` and then in sagaTask `getSaga1() getSaga2()`

Comment: This worked for me but I had to `sagaTask.toPromise()` instead of `sagaTask.done`. Also, since I exported sagas like this: `export default function* rootSaga() { yield all(arrayOfSagas) }` I had to `const newSagas = require('./sagas').default` and then just `sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(newSagas)`

Answer (score 13):

Update for `redux-saga` package in version `1.0.0` and newer:

Use @mpolci solution and just change

`sagaTask.done.then(() => {`

to

`sagaTask.toPromise().then(() => {`

and everything start working same.

See [Task](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#task-descriptor) documentation

Comment: Is this type of answer what StackOverlow's editing option is for? Or maybe that requires more reputation first?